# NodeJs - Loopback : How to upload file on google cloud storage

Tags: cloud, storage, loopbackjs

In loopback framework, we have a module LoopBack Storage Component. It's support for many clouds except Google Cloud Storage. But I have to use Google Cloud.

Comment: could you please add some info? what is exactly your problem?

Comment: I am a newbie in Node and loopback .. so I dont know how to upload file on Google Cloud Storage. Could you please give me some help? which module ( component ) in Loopback can support this? how to implement it. thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

It should support Google out of the box because it uses pkgcloud lib which has support for Google Cloud. Try simply adding a config entry to the providers.json file.

For more info on how to do that check [Loopback storage component](http://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Storage+component%20Storage%20component) documentation and also [pkgcloud](https://github.com/pkgcloud/pkgcloud/blob/master/docs/providers/google.md#using-storage) config format for Google Cloud.

I'd just try something like this in the providers.json:

```
{
    "google": {
        "keyFilename": "/path/to/a/keyfile.json",
        "projectId": "your-project-id"
    }
}
```