# Google Cloud Storage support for LoopBack

Tags: loopbackjs

According to Loopbacks' storage component document, it doesn't support Google Cloud Storage. But as the component uses pkgcloud to support the cloud based storage services; and pkgcloud did have the support for CGS. Is there a quick and safe way (even with paid solution) that we can make LoopBack works with Google Cloud Storage?

Thanks,

Comment: May reach a wider audience by also asking in the chat room and forums:
 https://gitter.im/strongloop/loopback 
 https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/loopbackjs

Comment: The documentation doesn't say that it doesn't support Google Cloud. It only says that it has Node.js and REST APIs for managing binary content in cloud providers, **including** Amazon, Rackspace, Openstack, Azure. Check the answer I gave to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30022591/nodejs-loopback-how-to-upload-file-on-google-cloud-storage

Comment: @AlexandruSavin: you're right, it works out of the box even the document doesn't say it :-).  Great! Tks a lot.